# Android Delphi XE8 Tela inicial

Tags: android, delphi

Bom dia pessoal,

Gostaria de saber se tem como remover a tela incial(icone da chama seguido da tela preta) que aparaece nos aplicativos desenvolvidos no Delphi XE8.

Grato.

Answer (score 1):

Já consegui resolver pessoal...

> Project -> Options -> Application -> Artwork, desmarcar a
>   opção "**Include Splash image**".